# Moving GPUImage Layer with Finger

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I have a base `GPUImagePicture (Layer 1)` and then another `GPUImagePicture (Layer 2)` that I have added a bunch of `filters` to.

When I put them together into one image they look fine but what I would like to do is move `Layer 2` with my finger to different positions on `Layer 1`. Is this possible without using something like `Cocos2D`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add an `GPUImageTransformFilter` with an affine transform set correctly to translation  to one of your `GPUImagePicture` **before blending**.
 If you need to make a more sophisticated manipulation I think that you should extract from one of the original image the correct portion, redraw in a transparent background image (same size of the first one) and then blend.
To build the affine transform to apply you can easily use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on a touch detecting overlay view.

Comment: Found a similar answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031006/blending-with-gpuimage-how-to-control-the-position-of-the-second-image-on-top-o